# Deviation from 2D trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, mathematics, projectile, models

I need to find out how far a ball is from the predicted trajectory in 2 dimensional space and I know the start and end position of the ball in both dimensions. Along with that I know the initial velocity and the angle at which the ball was launched.

**Every single variable is known in this picture.**
[image]

The problem is that I can predict where the ball is going to land based on the angle α and the initial velocity v<sub>0</sub>, but the actual landing is a bit off due to variables assumed to be zero (wind, friction, etc.) and I need a mathematical way of calculating this deviation.

NOTE: The mathematical model may not include calculus as we haven't covered that part of our curriculum yet.

*Any suggestions on how to do that?*

Comment: This may be off-topic, but... *what exactly* are $x_\text{slut}$ and $y_\text{slut}$?!

Comment: More to the point: What's wrong with just calculating by how much percent your predictions are off, given the actual data? Another often-used, basic method from *error analysis* is using the standard deviation.

Comment: Are you trying to make a mathematical model to figure out by how much your original mathematical model is off by?

Comment: @Danu slut is Danish for end

Comment: @HDE226868 that is the exact task I've been given...

Comment: Okay. The key words here are (once again) *error analysis*. There's a [famous, basic textbook by Taylor](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Error-Analysis-Uncertainties-Measurements/dp/093570275X) on this subject

Comment: Would you consider editing those $x$ and $y$ subscripts in the diagram? That's a somewhat offensive word in English.

Comment: @paisanco I know but it is not exactly easy as it is a picture which I received as a picture and would require quite a bit of work.

Comment: Look at [what we expect for homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).  I'm not clear about what you are asking.  You can do the calculation.  Are you asking how to calculate the *actual* landing point, having observed that it is different than the predicted value?  If so:  that is impossible, because you cannot know the *exact* values of the initial conditions.  There will also be effects (e.g. air drag) which the simple analysis ignores.  If not:  what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting that the force due to air resistance is usually modeled as
$$\vec{F} \propto -\vec{v} \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \vec{F} \propto -|v|^2 \hat{v} $$
Intuitively this makes sense: the faster you go, the more drag you should experience. The minus sign means that the force acts in opposition to the direction you are travelling.

Since the force is proportional to velocity, the force will change at each point in time. Therefore, it is *impossible* to model drag forces without using calculus. You would need to find the equations of motion and integrate.

That said, as others have mentioned you can just make an estimation of how much error will be introduced by:

- not knowing the initial conditions exactly
- ignoring non-conservative forces (friction, air resistance)

The best way to do this is to do the calculation and run the experiment and see how far you are off for a few different sets of initial conditions. That should give you a pretty good estimate of how much your model deviates from reality.